How to use object info / particle info in geo nodes?

I have a simple setup here. I would like each point to have a different color. This setup should show each point having a different shade of gray, but it does not - because technically this mesh containing the geonode mod is a single object. If I use the 'random' socket of the particle info node, I would get similar results. Ultimately I want each point to be a particular color, so that when zoomed out, you see an image. But this is the first step towards getting there.

just use your "own" random value with store named attribute from 0 to 1 and use that as attribute

Thanks! Ok now how can I use a colorramp with that in geonodes

Ok nevermind. That is good. I will have to post a new question for how to mask particular points based on an input image. Thanks. you answered the question!

Use the Point Info node:

Not the Object Info node.
